# How to overcome keyboard configuration in VMWare Player ?

Tags: vmware, virtual-machine, vmware-player, vmware-tools

Sorry for asking a stupid question but I have a problem that makes me crazy. I am trying to install a program on my VMware Player, but while writing the password since it includes " # " character inside of the password I always get incorrect login error. 
I am using an english keyboard and when I try to write " # " , i always get a different character from it. 
Do you know how I can overcome this keyboard fault ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Which keyboard is selected on virtual machine? Do OS uses same keyboard as the one in your _real_ pc? For example: if your pc uses an english kbd and your vm is using italian kbd the behaviour is exactly what you're describing...

Comment: I really don't know which keyboard is choosen in OS keyboard, maybe u are right. How I can look for the configuration ? Dont I have an option that changes all VMWare Player's configuration ? Because I think I can not change the configuration, since I am just installing a software and I just can see installation phase

Comment: Keep that software you're installing off. Focus on operating system: are you using Windows, Linux, MacOS? Change keybaord settings on operating system running on virtual machine!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change keyboard settings on operating system running on virtual machine.